# Django: Populate a table based on incerted value from other table

Tags: django, model, populate, auto

I need to set a start date and end date on a table (Week) and based on these values, another table (Day) is automatically populated with the days between those dates.

My models are:

```
class Week(models.Model):
class Meta:
    constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['sub_unit', 'initial_date', 'last_date'], name='unique_item')]
    ordering = ['-initial_date']
    verbose_name = 'Week'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Weeks'

sub_unit = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='SubUnit')
initial_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True, verbose_name='Initial Date')
last_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True, verbose_name='Last Date')

def __str__(self):
    return '{} - Week from {} to {}'.format(self.sub_unit, self.initial_date, self.last_date)


class Day(models.Model):
class Meta:
    constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['week', 'day'], name='unique_item')]
    ordering = ['-day']
    verbose_name = 'Day'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Days'

week = models.ForeignKey(Week, related_name='week', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
day = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True, verbose_name='day')

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.day)
```

Can some one put me in right direction. Thanks!

Comment: please correct the indentation

Comment: Why not use datetime and timedelta ?